# Can't create an object in a namespaced class

Tags: php, namespaces, fuelphp

I have a structure something like this

```
namespace Html;  

class MyHtml extends Fuel\Core\Html {
        private $table = null;

        public function __construct($table) {
            $this->table = $table;
        }

        public function textarea() { 

        }
    ...
```

On my template

```
<article class="modal hide fade" id="add-journal">
                <section class="modal-header">Add Journal</section>
                <section class="modal-body">
                    <?php 
                        $form = new Html\MyHtml('form-item');
                        ...other code...
                    ?>
                </section>
                <section class="modal-footer"></section>
            </article>
```

I get this error:

```
ErrorException [ Error ]: Class 'Html\MyHtml' not found
```

This might not be much of a fuelphp question, but more of a PHP one. Does this mean I can't make objects based on my class if it's in a namespace? Do I have to provide a static function for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating your object with a relative namespace path.

Use a absolute path to the namespace:

```
 $form = new \Html\MyHtml('form-item');
```

And, of course your *autoloader* needs to automatic include your file. If you have not a autoloader make sure to include the file:

```
include_once 'path_to_your_class/your_classfile.php';
$form = new \Html\MyHtml('form-item');
```

Comment: This will work. But for using a framework, I need to follow on the autoloader part. However, I can't seem to find it in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$form = new \Html\MyHtml('form-item');`.

The `\` means that you are starting from the root. If you do not start from the root, you are searching for `Html\MyHtml` from the namespace that the template is part of.

In addition, make sure that class is loaded using an autoloader or `require_once`.

Answer (score 0):

FuelPHP Views are parsed in the global namespace, so in this specific case Html\MyHTML should work.

The big question is where have you created this class, and since it is using non-standard class naming, did you add it to the bootstrap? FuelPHP's autoloader is case-sensitive, so it will look for a Myhtml class...

Second question is that I wonder what you're exactly trying to do? FuelPHP's HTML class is a static helper class, instantiating it is rather pointless, since it only contains static methods...